# Inverse image of a borel set is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have a pretty dumb doubt.

For a function $f$ with $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we say

> $f$ is *measurable* if $f^{-1}((\infty, a))$ is (Lebesgue) measurable for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Define $\mathcal{P}$ to be the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that for $P \in \mathcal{P}$, $f^{-1}(P)$ is measurable. Now note that $f^{-1}((\infty, b)) \cap f^{-1}((\infty,a))^c = (a,b)$, so all the open intervals lie in $\mathcal{P}$.

Also since we know that each open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as countable union of disjoint open intervals, by countable additivity of the Lebesgue measure, we have

> All the open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ is in $\mathcal{P}$ ($\dagger$)

Also by the properties of Lebesgue measure, we have countable union, intersects and complements of elements lie in $\mathcal{P}$ too, so we have

> $\mathcal{P}$ is a sigma algebra ($\ddagger$)

1. It follows from $\dagger$ and $\ddagger$ that $\mathcal{P}$ contains the Borel $\sigma$ algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ (since Borel $\sigma$ algebra is pretty much defined as the smallest $\sigma$ algebra containing all the open sets, so since $\mathcal{P}$ contains all the open sets the Borel set must be a subset of that), right ?
2. It doesn't follow from the definition that inverse image of a Lebesgue measurable set should be a Borel set, right ?
3. The why the definition of a measurable function is not strengthened to show that $f^{-1}(M)$ is Lebesgue measurable whenever $M$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ ? If you define $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,2]$ by $f(x) = c(x) + x$ (where $c(x)$ is the [Cantor Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function)) then $f(x)$ is measurable by the original criterion but not by the modified one. What more do we gain by relaxing the definition to only have $f^{-1}(B)$ is Lebesgue measurable whenver $B$ is a Borel subset $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: You are correct in stating that $\mathcal P$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra as a subcollection. Further I don't really get you. Do you wonder why it is not demanded that preimages of Lebesgue measurable sets are Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: @drhab Yup, I wonder " why it is not demanded that preimages of Lebesgue measurable sets are Lebesgue measurable?"